# How to loop over a list of Organic Group users using Rules

Tags: rules, organic-groups

When a user requests to join an Organic Group, I want to send an email to the group's admins. I've found this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742925/how-to-send-an-email-to-drupal-7-organic-groups-role-members/23301910) which helps with selecting users with the appropriate role, but I can't for the life of me get a list of just the users from the current group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any of that php stuff tenken is saying.
Just install [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), create a new rule reacting on a user joining a group and use the action "Get group members from group audience". For this to work, you'll have to add to the conditions in the rule that the node is in fact a group.

Comment: A screenshot of this approach can be seen in my question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190139/email-all-organic-group-members-when-a-subgroup-is-created

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to:

- define a new variable in your Rule called `$users_in_group`.
- use a `php script` step to use an `EntityFieldQuery` or Organic Groups API call to list the users in a Group.
- Assign `$users_in_group` to the result of your php-script business logic.
- Use a `Rules Loop` to loop over the result array of `$users_in_group`
- use a final `php-script` rules step to do the logic you describe in your link for the appropriate user.