# OG Subgroups - call function _og_subgroups_get_inherited_users

Tags: rules, organic-groups

I am trying to create a custom rule for OG Subgroups to email the members of a subgroup when content is added to it.

In og_subgroups.common.inc I can see the function I wish to use to return the inherited users of a subgroup

```
function _og_subgroups_get_inherited_users($group_type, $group_id, $states = array(OG_STATE_ACTIVE))
```

In my custom rule action I'm not sure what I should be passing to the function as $group_type and $group_id parameters. I have tried things like "node" and the NID of the group:

```
$array = _og_subgroups_get_inherited_users("node", 27);
```

Once I get it working with a hardcoded node e.g. node 27 I will then try to pass the details of the parent groupd that content has been added to.

I'm using OG Subgroups ﻿﻿7.x-2.0-beta1. For the full background into why I'm creating this custom rule action you can see my [original drupal answers question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190139/email-all-organic-group-members-when-a-subgroup-is-created)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a custom og_subgroups.rules.inc file. For details of this see my answer in: [Email all Organic Group members when a subgroup is created](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190139/email-all-organic-group-members-when-a-subgroup-is-created/192485#192485)

The line in question above needed to be:

```
$inherited_users = _og_subgroups_get_inherited_users("node", $nid);
```