# Create view of members inherited from OG Subgroups

Tags: views, organic-groups

I have the following OG Structure:

> Organisation (group)
>
> > Property (subgroup)
> >
> > > Claim (subgroup content)

I would like to be able to list all the group members of a property, including inherited members. The 'OG Extras group members' view is similar to what I need. It produces a list of users who are members of an Organisation as expected:
[image: users who are members of an Organisation - working]

However when in a subgroup the view does not show the inherited users:

[image: Subgroup does not show inherited users]

The users have been inherited correctly by the subgroup as they are shown when you choose the 'group' tab and then click 'people':

[image]

Could you please suggest how I can create a view which shows inherited users?

Comment: Wait... by "Views" you mean something different than everyone else..? I meant the [module "Views"](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

Comment: @turion, no I mean the normal views. I looked more into the code I mentioned. It added the ability to get 'The OG groups and subgroups of the logged in user' as an argument in views. Mentioning it was confusing so I have removed it from the question

Comment: I was confused because you have the tab "View" open in your first two images, and I thought that you maybe meant that. Anyways. Do you know how to use the Views UI? You can easily create a view of users with a group context and add the right relations. I think your problem should be solvable that way. If you have no idea, what I'm talking about, let me know, and I'll try to explain.

Comment: Thanks @Turion, I am comfortable with building views. The issue is that the OG subgroup does not have members that you can view. The members are inherited from the parent group node. So I believe I would need to do something clever with getting the subgroup of the page being viewed as an arguement, creating a relationship with the parent node and then using that relationship to show the members. However I was not able to get this working

Comment: yes, but that's the kind of thing you can do with the Views UI. You need to use contextual filters.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried with contextual filters. I said arguments before using the old terminolgy by mistake - 'Until recently, contextual filters were called arguments in Views'.

Comment: So the subgroup should be the argument to the view, and you want to retrieve the parent group from the subgroup. Then you list all members of the parent group. What exactly doesn't work with it?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the view you tried to configure so far, and say what it should have done?

Comment: I have realised that while I have managed to create subgroups I am not creating them in the same way as is suggested here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1345212#comment-5363040 instead I am relating the child groups myself with an entity reference field. This allows me to use entity reference prepopulate to choose the parent group depending on the page the user is on when they create a subgroup. I expect the fact I seem to be using subgroups in an unconventional way is why the views aren't working how you expect. Thanks for all your help @Turion

Comment: I was wanting to create the view of members to aid me emailing them when new content was added. I have actually added a custom og_subgroup.rules.inc file to the OG Subgroups module that allows me to get the users of the group's parent using rules so that I can email them all.

Comment: For the details of the patch above see: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190139/email-all-organic-group-members-when-a-subgroup-is-created/192485#192485

Comment: Glad you found a way!